# Require lib.loc and Required base packages

Tags: r, package

Say I have a set of external packages in folder `x`. And I want to load one of these packages, for example through

```
require(my.package, lib.loc='x')
```

Any requirement (dependency) of `my.package` that is external, will be looked for in the same folder `x`. What about base packages? Do I need to copy the base packages also into the folder `x` or will `R` fallback into the default folder despite a different `lib.loc` specified?

Comment: Can you explain why you would be using `require()` for base packages?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that I want to `require` a base package.  What I meant was that if `my.package` depends on a base package, would `R` try to load that also from `lib.loc`, which apparently was a question that didn't make much sense.

Comment: If you want the see a description of what happens when R is loaded then type `?Startup`. Not all the "base packages" get loaded right away and so you sometimes may need to require what you might have thought were a "base package" in your `.Rprofile` file. The interpreter, i.e. the true "base"-package would be loaded from the environment variable `$HOME`'s value.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried this right now with a new set up and observed that at least on Mac OS X, base packages will still be included from the default lib path.